# Delete worksheet if name isn't found in a cell in column D

Tags: excel, vba

I asked a question earlier about a worksheet_change macro I was working on. It's almost complete, but now I'm stumped. I'm trying to loop through all the worksheets in the workbook, and if the worksheet's name is not found in any cell in range D6:D34, I want to delete the worksheet. How can I write this? I'm completely stumped. Current code:

```
Private Sub WorkSheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Run faster
Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'Just in case

'To add worksheets automatically
Dim shtName As Variant
For Each shtName In Sheets(1).Range("D6:D34")
    If shtName <> "" Then
        If WorksheetExists((shtName)) Then 'do nothing
        Else
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
            ActiveSheet.Name = shtName
            Sheets("Admin").Select
        End If
    Else 'there's no sheet
    End If
Next

'to delete sheets with no matching value
Dim ws_count As Integer
Dim i As Long

ws_count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
For i = 1 To ws_count

'what do I need here???

Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

Function WorksheetExists(sName As String) As Boolean
    WorksheetExists = Evaluate("ISREF('" & sName & "'!A1)")
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

ws_count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

For i = ws_count To 2 Step -1
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i)
    If IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name,Sheets(1).Range("D6:D34"),0)) then 
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ws.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If

Next i
```

Comment: Hi Tim. Getting Run-time error '-2147221080 (800401a8)': Automation error

Comment: On which line? Is your sheet list in a different workbook ?

Comment: It's not letting me debug, I just have the end option and excel crashes : /. Sheet is not stored in another workbook.

Comment: The worksheet with the list is not getting deleted, right?  Are *any* sheets getting deleted?

Comment: I think the loop counter should be like this "For i = ws_count To 2 Step -1" to exclude sheets(1) from getting deleted which will also produce an error.

Comment: @sktneer - yes, that would probably help but should not have caused the error (at least on the first run, it should not have errored...)

Comment: Yes you are right. The reported error will not be produced even if the code tries to delete the only available sheet in the workbook.

Comment: @sktneer got it! It was deleting the first sheet, which I assumed was because the code wasn't navigating pages and just going to `ws.delete` and deleting the page. I changed it to `for I ws_count to 2 step -1` and it's working! thanks for all your help, both of you

Comment: @Tim Williams would you mind editing your answer for others who are interested?